# How do I update the model on click only (angular-strap typeahead and json)

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-strap, ng-submit

I'm having trouble figuring out how to have dynamic data only update when the user selects from the typeahead menu or clicks the search button.

Right now, the dynamic content pertaining to the search query updates automatically when the input value is changed (content disappears). I want the content to stay in view until a new selection has been either clicked in the typeahead list or clicked by the search button.

Any insight at all would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Plunker demo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jVmHwIwJ0KOKCnX6QjVa?p=preview

Code:

```
<!-- HTML -->
  <body ng-controller="MainController">

<!-- Search -->
<div class="well">
  <p>Search the term "content"</p>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group clearfix search">
      <input type="text" ng-model="selectedContent" ng-options="query as query.searchQuery for query in searchData" bs-typeahead="bs-typeahead" class="form-control search-field"/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary search-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- Dynamic Content -->
<div class="well">
  <h4>{{ selectedContent.contentTitle }}</h4>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in selectedContent.headlines">{{item.headline}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
<!-- typeahead template -->
<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu" tabindex="-1" ng-show="$isVisible()" role="select">
<li role="presentation" ng-repeat="match in $matches" ng-class="{active: $index == $activeIndex}">
  <a href="" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-click="$select($index, $event)" ng-bind="match.label"></a>
</li>
```

```
<!-- JS -->
var app = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap'])
.config(function ($typeaheadProvider) {
  angular.extend($typeaheadProvider.defaults, {
    template: 'ngstrapTypeahead.html',
    container: 'body'
   });
});

function MainController($scope, $templateCache, $http) {

  $scope.selectedContent = '';

  $http.get('searchData.json').then(function(response){
    $scope.searchData = response.data;
    return $scope.searchData;
  });

};
```

Comment: Don't know how typeahead work but you can use different model and update the real model onclick.

Comment: Thanks jcubic, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can experiment with something like: `onclick="update()" ng-model="model"` and `$scope.update = function() { $scope.value = $scope.model; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a directive such as this:

```
app.directive('mySearch', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel){
      ngModel.$render = function(){
         if (angular.isObject($scope.selectedContent)) {
           $scope.clickedContent = $scope.selectedContent;
         }
      }
       $scope.updateModel = function() {
         $scope.clickedContent = $scope.selectedContent;
      }
    }
  }

})
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yX8tstinH4lTYPW5DzHQ?p=preview)

Edit:

I added using the ngModelController. The function you set `ngModel.$render` to gets called whenever the model updates. If you click the typahead popup, then the model `selectedContent` will be an object, otherwise it'll be a string. If it's an object (meaning the user clicked the typahead popup) we do the same as we did in the `updateModel` function.

Comment: thanks Mosho, this seems like the best approach, although I'm having trouble applying the updateModel() directive to the typeahead li anchor. Any thoughts on how this could work?

Comment: @MuddyMudSkipper Updated the answer and demo.

Comment: Sorry, I could have explained that better. Right now, the updateModel() directive works just for the search button. I'm trying to get it to also work when the user clicks an li from the typeahead dropdown. So ultimately, the model should update when clicking the search button and clicking an li in the typeahead.

Comment: Thanks Mosho. I'm trying to get updateModel() to work when a user clicks an <a> from the typeahead menu as well (in the typeahead.html template). It's not working at the moment, here is an updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jVmHwIwJ0KOKCnX6QjVa?p=preview